# Extract chromaticness/relative chroma from HSV

Tags: c#, javascript, php, colors

I am trying to figure out how to get chromaticness out of HSV (alternative RGB). Problem is; I barely know what chromaticness is. According to the small information available on the net it is usually refered to "relative chroma" which is a combination of hue and saturation.

From http://www.huevaluechroma.com/012.php:

> Another term for the concept of chroma relative to an assumed maximum
>   is chromaticness from the Swedish NCS system

I do have a the RGB which I have converted to HSV in PHP. I hope there is anyone out there who can provide their expertise in this question because there seems to be very limited information documented. I need it to validate NCS-codes.

Chromaticness calculation this far:

```
   //$hsv is array(h, s, v), maximum considered to be 10000        
   $chroma = $hsv[1] * $hsv[2];
   $chromaticness = $chroma / 10000;
```

For instance, the color S 2065-B (#0073B0) gives me chromaticness 69% using the calculation above when it should be 65%. Also, the color S 0580-Y (#FECB00) gives me 99% when it should be 80%?

The HSV in these examples I am getting are:

#0073B0 { 'H' => 200.79545454545, 'S' => 100, 'V' => 69.019607843137 }

#FECB00 { 'H' => 47.952755905512, 'S' => 100, 'V' => 99.607843137255 }

This solution is welcome in any programming language, however I am coding in PHP so it will probably be converted to that.

Comment: Chromaticness in the NCS system has nothing to do with hue.  It's comparable to saturation in HSV.  See the diagrams in http://www.prominentpaints.co.za/ColoursAndCalculators/NCSColour, for example.

Comment: I am not sure I'm following you here, I am using saturation and lightness in the calculation above.

Comment: Can you provide the hsv values you calculate for the two colors you mention?

Comment: Updated with HSV arrays I am getting from this. :)

Answer (score 4):

Chroma is the third attribute of the Munsell system beyond colour-hue and lightness/brightness.

Chroma in general defines colorfulness of the hue in question: 
i.e. the attribute of color that indicates the degree of departure of the color from the gray of the same lightness. From here *Color Space and Its Divisions* by Rolf G. Kuehni (amply available at google books)

> Chroma and saturation are identical for two colors having the same hue and lightness. Saturation remains constant regardless of brightness or lightness. Chroma, on the other hand, increases as lightness increases.

The coded **formulas for Chroma** are given [here](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/HSV-RGB_Conversion)

Until you consider color-gamuts Chroma remains an open-ended quantity - ranging as it does from 0 to infinity.

NCS **chromaticness is Chroma specified as a percentage** - where 100% corresponds to some finite upper limit, [see ISSN-03912051](http://books.google.it/books?id=RuGk8DqlrD4C&lpg=PA98&ots=N7TzPLDRid&dq=NCS%20chromaticness&pg=PA97#v=onepage&q&f=false).  You will need to chose that finite value to get a good working dynamic range in your computational system.

Trust that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My problem with this calculation of chromaticness is that it deviates too much from the NCS-samples I am given. If I set an upper limit to calculate a percentage that percentage has no logical connection at all to the NCS-percentage after several of samples.

Comment: Also I am certain my RGB -> HSV calculations are properly working.

Comment: When you say "it deviates too much from the NCS-samples I am given" are you talking about a color chip that you compare to a tile on the monitor screen?  If so there are may factors involved in an appearance mismatch.  Your task then becomes one of calibrating your particular monitor to your standard samples.  Take a look at this article  http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03204528 or similar, for how to do proper monitor calibration for repeatable psychophysical experiments.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. What I mean is that the chromaticness in the NCS does not match my calculation of the chromaticness. There is no pattern which leads me to think there is something wrong with the algorithm. I have NCS samples which also show RGB, this is why I am positive my calculation is wrong.

Comment: When you write: //$hsv is array(h, s, v), maximum considered to be 10000        
   $chroma = $hsv[1] * $hsv[2];
   $chromaticness = $chroma / 10000; are you sure the array is not zero indexed.  Is hue really  $hsv[0] and saturation  $hsv[1] ?

Comment: Yes, I have verified this aswell. It is saturation * brightness I am calculating. :)

Comment: Instead of `hue*brightness` you could try computing RGB from your HSV then using `Chroma = Max(R,G,B) = Min(R,G,B)` - but then you still need to get a _chromaticness_ from that Chroma value.

Comment: @Undrium Can you add one or two examples in your question showing what your official NCS reference gives you, and what you own calculation gives you? That would help pinpoint the possible problem.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff That gives me precisely the same answer as the examples I'm giving now.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Updated my question with two examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you are having is related to the fact that the four basis colors in the NCS system do not all have 100% values in the HSV system.

For example, a fully saturated and fully bright orange in the NCS system would be half way on the HSV arc between between NCS yellow and NCS red.  NCS yellow has an HSV Value of 100%, but NCS red has an HSV Value of only 77%, so this orange would have a Value of about 88.5%.  Nonetheless, the NCS chromaticity would still be 100%, even though your calculation from HSV would give it a chromaticity of 88.5%.  (There's also the issue that NCS red is only 99% saturated in the HSV system, but I'm ignoring that.)

The HSV values for the NCS basis colors are as follows:

```
white 100%
black 0%
green 63%
red 77%
yellow 100%
blue 74%
```

source:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Color_System

I think what you need to do is, after you've calculated the NCS GY/GB/RY/RB "hue", calculate the maximal HSV Value for that NCS hue based on proration from the two relevant NCS basis colors, then calculate the NCS chromaticity as a fraction of that maximal HSV Value (i.e., divide by that maximal Value, if we're dealing with numbers between 0 and 1).  Thus, we would give a saturated Y50R orange with an HSV Value of 22.125% a chromaticity of 25%, since 22.125% is 25% of the maximal value of 88.5% for Y50R orange.

Note that this means you will have to deal with RGB/HSV colors that fall above the maximal Values for NCS colors.  In those cases I'd probably just scale the HSV Value back to the maximum for NCS colors with the same hue.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean when you say "HSV value of 22.125%", could you elaborate that a little?

Comment: By "HSV value" I mean the "V" part of HSV.  By "22.125%", I mean 22.125% of whatever the maximum value of "HSV value" is; often the HSV value is expressed as a percentage or fraction.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to calculate what you are mentioning, though. I have updated my example with the HSV-arrays I am getting from my functions.